# $\mathbb Z$ basis of the module $\mathbb Z [\zeta]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, algebraic-number-theory, roots-of-unity

Given an $n$-th root of unity $\zeta$, consider the $\mathbb Z$-module $M := \mathbb Z[\zeta]$.

1. Does this module have a special name?
2. Does a basis exist for every $n$? And if so, is there an algorithm to find a basis given an $n$?

I was just playing around with this, and noticed that for $n=3$ we have e.g. the basis $(1,\zeta)$ because $1+\zeta = -\zeta^2$. For $n=4$ we obviously have the basis $(1,i)$, but I was unable to generalize this for an arbitrary $n$.

Comment: As you are probably aware, a $\mathbb{Z}$-module is just an abelian group.

Comment: I don't agree with the *just* in your comment =)

Comment: Assuming *primitive* $n$-th root here.

Comment: @ccorn a non primitive $n$-th root is a primitive $m$-th root for some $m$, so I'm not sure it makes any difference.

Comment: Yes you're probably both right, but I agree for readability it would make sense to define $\zeta$ as a primitive root.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know if you consider this a special name, but the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$ is the ring of integers for the number field $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$. This is (IMO, anyway) a nontrivial fact, but you can find its proof in Neukirch (see below), or (for the case $n$ prime) in Samuel's ''Algebraic Theory of Numbers''—[this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17289/quick-proof-of-the-fact-that-the-ring-of-integers-of-q-zeta-n-is-z-zeta-n) link might also be helpful to you. Correspondingly, it is free as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, and its rank is given by the degree $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta):\mathbb{Q}] = \varphi(n)$, where $\varphi$ is the Euler totient function. The basis for $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module is given by $1, \zeta, \zeta^{2}, \ldots, \zeta^{d-1}$, where $d = \varphi(n)$. As a reference, see Neukirch's ''Algebraic Number Theory'', page 60, Proposition 10.2.

Comment: Thank you very much, thats an excellent answer=)

Comment: @flawr: very glad I could help! :)

Comment: Actually, OP did not ask for the ring of integers of $\Bbb Q(\zeta)$ — he asked only for the ring $\Bbb Z[\zeta]$. Isn’t it the case that if $\xi$ is integral over $\Bbb Z$, the module $\Bbb Z[\xi]$ is always $\Bbb Z$-free? After all, the module is finitely generated and torsion-free.

Comment: @Lubin: you're absolutely right, so this answer is overkill. It seemed maybe that the OP was wondering what was special about the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$, so this is what came to mind for me. :)

Comment: Overkill maybe, but much more instructive than what I would have written.

Comment: @Lubin I am still grateful that I learned about the context of number fields. Can you recommend any reference for learning module theory? This is a topic that I never really got in touch with.

Comment: This geezer is out of touch with the best modern literature. When I taught commutative algebra, I would have used Atiyah-MacDonald, but you’ll have to ask others than me. I think A-MacD is still available, but at a ridiculously high price.

Answer (score 1):

The *ring* $\mathbb Z[\zeta]$ is called the ring of *cyclotomic integers*.

Comment: Wikipedia and Mathworld both say that the term *cyclotomic integers* is only used for $\mathbb Z[\zeta]$ where $\zeta = e^{2\pi  i/p}$ where $p$ is *prime*, do you agree?

Comment: @flawr, indeed, but I don't see why this should be. Other sources say that  *cyclotomic integers* are the algebraic Integers in a cyclotomic field. See for instance, http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0022-4049(81)90086-4 and http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1965-19-090/S0025-5718-1965-0180545-X/.